# Unblock element on specific date?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a list of elements that I'd like to render, but have interaction stay blocked until a specific day. I'm looking to unveil one per day for a span of 30 days. I've looked a little into the jQuery BlockUI and read a bit about settimeout and setinterval, but I'm not really familiar with either of these.

Is there a way to specify an element to unblock on a certain date?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are about doing things at a time relative to the time the script runs (possibly when the page is loaded), so that probably won't help you. Are you using any server technology, or is this a static page?

Comment: I would recommend putting this logic server-side. As the javascript reads the date from the client.  And they can change it to whatever they want to.

Comment: In addition to the client computer controlling the JavaScript date, not everyone will be polite enough to visit your site using a browser, let alone a browser with JavaScript enabled. This really should be controlled server-side. Otherwise, the element will only be blocked for a fraction of the visitors to your site.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't control this server side as I'm regulated to front end and only have the ability to build a static page.